# Is SMTP over SSL possible in the Balsa email client?

Tags: email, ssl, mail-user-agent

In Balsa 2.5.1 is it possible to connect to SMTP with port 465 with 
SSL? The IMAP setup has an SSL option which disables the TLS choices, 
but I do not see anything similar when setting up SMTP. I know that 
SMTP port 587 with STARTTLS is the standard-compliant way to connect 
(and the same with IMAP port 143 STARTTLS vs 
IMAP port 993 SSL), but my mail service doesn't seem to support this 
yet. I have tried every combination I can come up with in the SMTP 
settings in Balsa, but nothing seems to work. I have been able to 
connect in every other email client I have used, so I don't think there 
is any problem with the server (other than supporting the latest 
standards, ha).

Also, when using the compose window in Balsa and typing in the To 
field, after hitting tab it takes you to another To field and you have 
to hit tab once or twice more to get to the Subject field. Is there any 
way to have the tab press after typing the first To address take you 
directly to the Subject field (I didn't notice anything in the options, but perhaps I overlooked it)?

Thank you.

Comment: It has TLS option , but doesn't has port number.

Comment: Right, it has a place for the SMTP server, but no place to enter a port, and I have tried adding the port to the server entry by adding `:465` after the server name. Then the TLS options are "Use TLS:" `Never`, `If Possible`, or `Required`. But, none of these settings work for me with or without the `:465` added after the SMTP server.

Comment: i suggest you use evoltion, i use it and enjoy ...!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just wanted to try something different (meaning Balsa). I like the simple layout.

Comment: Why would you down-vote this (whoever did)? This is a valid question.